# Asynctask handling long http calls

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> public class NetworkService extends AsyncTask {

```
String url="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx";;
public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String jsonStr = "";
public NetworkService(String api) {
    url = url+path+api;
}
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

    builder.append(jsonStr);
    return null;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    //PostPaidFragment obj = (PostPaidFragment)page;
    //obj.createList(builder, container, rootView);
    delegate.processFinish(builder);
}
```

}

okey this is the api call, am using

> ```
>           final NetworkService networkCall = new NetworkService(url);
>              networkCall.delegate = this;
>             networkCall.execute();
>             Handler handler = new Handler();
>             detect = 0;
>             handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void run() {
>                             try
>                             {
>                                 if (networkCall.getStatus() == NetworkService.Status.RUNNING)
>                                 {
>                                     networkCall.cancel(true);
>                                     ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
>                                     progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
>                                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(BBActivity.this, R.string.serverError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>                                     toast.show();
>                                                              }
>                             }
>                             catch(Exception tre)
>                             {       
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }, 30000);
> ```

basically, i make http call. But if this http is taking long ( 30 seconds in this case), i stop it..and show connection to server error.
however, am having problem once this popup occurs...next http call am making is not working either.i am being forced to remove my app, and reinstall it to get it working.
any help?

here is service handler.java too

> public class ServiceHandler {

```
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The first HTTP connection is still alive before you make the 2nd request. Use the code below instead of using DefaultHttpClient directly.

```
public static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 200000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 200000);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, 
            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);

    return client;
}
```

Now modify this line from your code block

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getThreadSafeClient();

Comment: 200000, means 200 seconds right? i am getting an error though using this. the url returning to me wrong stuff...then usual.

Comment: Yes it is 200 seconds. Also this code snippet has been taken from one of my previous project, so it should work fine. Try it again and share me your code if it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

here is error i get on ur answer

> 09-17 16:58:14.539: I/System.out(29210): Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 - Error report
>
> ## HTTP Status 500 -
>
> **type** Exception report
>
> **message**
>
> **description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception** org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String com.netvariant.zain.sa.mobapp.api.v1.auth.AuthController.registerDevice(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header 'User-Agent' of type [java.lang.String]